# HTML table how i can insert values of that table to sql (laravel)

Tags: javascript, php

On Laravel test.blade.php i got this table with data, editable data. User see that table,adds some values to editable td.How i can parse that table with button onclick or code to sql table database.Tried Jquery to PHP conversion didnt worked (converted data to array in query and tried get array to php variable), tried Simple DOMS didnt worked too.

```
<table id="examplecopy10" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>code</th>
        <th>stuff</th>
        <th>editable stuff</th>
        <th>editable stufftwo</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($a as $b)
        <tr>
            <td>    {{  $b->id }} </td>
            <td>    {{  $b->code }} </td>
            <td>    {{  $b->stuff }} </td>
            <td contenteditable="true"></td>
            <td contenteditable="true"></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use some Javascript framework to do that. Vue js is the best idea, Vue js is support with Laravel, so you can use it easy. You can do any thing with Laravel and Vue js.